# Concat array value with output from 'count' calculation

Tags: javascript, php, sql, arrays

Hello and thank you for any help/direction you can provide.

In PHP, I have an array built from a mySQL query using adjacency tables (parent/multiple children). Separately, using a javascript function, I have calculated the number of children/grandchildren for EACH parent (from root down). Now, I would like to 'somehow' add this count to the 'name' value in the original array in the following format: 'name [count]'.

I've looked at (PHP) array_merge(), array_walk(), and array_values() but they do not work for this. I believe I'm making this more complicated than necessary so I'm hopeful someone has an easy solution.

What I'm thinking is using 'foreach' and creating a copy of the original array and then running the javascript function on each pass to calculate the count and then add it to the 'name' value but I'm not sure the best way to concat this 'count' to the 'name' value in the array. Any suggestions and/or a better way?

Here is the SQL query:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT CONCAT(primes.first_name, ' ', primes.last_name, ' [', domains.position_root, ']') value, domains.prime_id AS id, domains.mgr_id FROM domains INNER JOIN primes ON domains.prime_id = primes.prime_id WHERE domains.mgr_id = domains.id;
```

Here is partial output from the query:

```
[ { "value": "Jim Smith [AGM]", "id": "10003", "items": [ { "value": "Michael Jones [Senior Director]", "id": "10004", "items": [ { "value": "Ralph Henry [Director]", "id": "10012", "items": [ { "value": "Michael Peterson [Manager]", "id": "10046", "items": [] }, ...
```

Comment: Need example source array and what the result should be.

Comment: "they do not work" - not work how? What is your result? What are you expecting instead? Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ArSeN: Sorry ... new to this (and thank you for the link)  ... what I meant by "they do not work" is the functions they perform are different than what I'm trying to achieve. I listed them because I don't want anyone to think I haven't been trying to find the answer myself.

Comment: AbraCadaver: I have added to my original post. Thank you.